# Alfresco Quick Start in Alfresco Web Editor (AWE) insert image/link is not working

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-wqs

I am working on Alfresco Web Editor (AWE) while editing or creating article insert image/link panel text boxes are non editable. I am not getting any solution for this, can anyone help me with this?

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the problem you have?

Comment: i am trying to add image or link through the web editor, after insert image modal opens am trying to enter text but all the text boxes focus is not working, am not able to enter the text in fields